# Doctrine ODM - query for an article with the most views

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

i have an article document, for which i keep track of the read count. Now i want to run a query that would return the article which has the highest read count.

How would i go about this using doctrine odm?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't really worked with the ODM all that often yet, but I believe you could do it like this:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('Article')->sort('readCount', 'desc')->limit(1)->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Yep, that's what i did in the end.